# Crunchy postgres operator: What's the different and use cases between spec.instances.replicas and spec.instances?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, postgres-operator

I'm using postgres operator but got confusing of those two configs in the docs:

> PGO provides several ways to add replicas to make a HA cluster:
>
> - Increase the `spec.instances.replicas` value
> - Add an additional entry in `spec.instances`

https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/5.0.1/tutorial/high-availability/

So what is the difference (in term of HA benefit) between:

```yaml
spec:
  instances:
    - name: i1
      replicas: 2
```

vs

```yaml
spec:
  instances:
    - name: i1
      replicas: 1
    - name: i2
      replicas: 1
```

Why should I use first config over second config?

Comment: It seems that i1 has two replicas in the first case, whereas i2 is not even specified, whereas in the second case both i1 and i2 exist and both of them have a single replica each.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't know what's the benefit related to HA if I use first case over second case. Both results the creation of 2 pods, edited the question to add more clarifying

Comment: But thy are different instances. You might need two different instances.

Answer (score 0):

No accepted answer, so I asked on Github, here is the [issue link](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/issues/3754) and the answer:

> The advantage of the former (increasing the replicas count) is really just having a tidier spec and the convenience of simply increasing/decreasing one value to adjust your replicas. The advantage of the latter (adding separate instance specs) is that you can have different configurations for each instance. The possible configurations are documented here: